# find the values of the latest dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have these two datasets 
t5 and t6

[image]

I want to find the tax_id with the latest date

So I have used UNION instead of join

```
Select * from (
Select s_id, tax_id, date_of,
row_number() over(partition by s_id order by date_of) row_num
FROM
(Select * from t5
UNION
Select * from t6) s1) s2
```

```
1   123 2022-01-01  1
1   345 2022-01-10  2
2   234 2022-01-02  1
3   456 2022-01-03  1
3   458 2022-01-04  2
4   789 2022-01-04  1
4   789 2022-01-07  2
5   222 2022-01-05  1
5   222 2022-01-07  2
```

There is a value 2 with only have the same txn_date 
I also want to take that as the latest one

EDIT : Thanks for your help 
I am using SQL Server 
I want the output as below.

[image]

Comment: Please share your simple data as text not images so it can be easy for us to help you, and please tag the DBMS

Comment: And _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: You sort in descending order and keep the one with row number 1.

Answer (score 1):

Generate dataset using `UNION ALL` then apply `row_number()` on it to generate row numbers by descendant order and pick the ones with `rn = 1` :

```
with cte as (
  select s_id, tax_id, date_of, row_number() over (partition by s_id order by date_of desc ) as rn
  from (
    select * 
    from t5
    union all
    select * 
    from t6
  ) as s
)
select s_id, tax_id, date_of
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select everything from two tables with `UNION ALL` and then choose the latest date by `LIMIT 1`

```sql
SELECT * FROM t5
UNION
(SELECT * FROM t6)
ORDER BY date_of DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It would work for PostgreSQL, but I guess, for other DBMS it might work too.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell which dbms this is for.

Comment: The question asks to find `tax_id` with the latest date. Judging from the provided data example, there might be multiple `tax_id` with the same date. `LIMIT 1` will prevent finding all `tax_id` with the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

Use rownum = 1 for getting one data from list in Oracle SQL

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
  FROM t5
 UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM t6) sq
 WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY date_of desc
```

Comment: The question was afterwards tagged `sql-server`, where `rownum` is not supported.

Comment: @GMB that part was added after my answer. First tag list and description didn't include what kind of database was used for this question

Answer (score 0):

To find the latest date for each `tax_id` you could use the `GROUP BY` clause with `MAX` aggregate function.

For this query to work in the majority of DBMS, `date_of` has to be defined as a datetime type.

```
SELECT tax_id, MAX(date_of) AS max_date_of
FROM (SELECT tax_id, date_of FROM t5 UNION SELECT tax_id, date_of FROM t6) t
GROUP BY tax_id
```

Comment: (1) OP wants to partition by `s_id` rather than by `tax_id`. (2) The `group by` technique does not return the `tax_id` that correspond to the latest `s_id`, for this we need window functions instead (`row_number()` as in some of the other answers).